# How to use 'is' operator with a generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have the classes

```
abstract class MyGeneric<T>
{
    ...
}

class A : MyGeneric<int>
{
    ...
}
```

How can I check, using the `is` operator, if any object is an instance of class `MyGeneric`?

Something like this:

```
bool isGeneric = anyObj.GetType() is MyGeneric;
```

Comment: You should not `.GetType()` before checking.